# Remove duplicate values from api

Tags: angular, typescript, api, dropdown

I'm displaying values from the API in a dropdown menu. But there are some duplicate values that I want to remove.

```
[0: {CountryCode: "US", Prof ID: 31, Scope: "National"} 
1: {CountryCode: "US" , Prof ID: 31, Scope: "Self"}
2: {CountryCode: "US", Prof ID: 31, Scope: "Specialty"}
3: {CountryCode: "IT", Prof ID: 31, Scope: "Carting"}]
```

**HTMLcode:

```
              <div class="col ">
                <label for="country" class="control-label" required>Country:</label><br>
                <select  required="" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="detailM" formControlName="PropertyCountryCode"> 
                    <option [ngValue]="null"></option>    
                    <option  *ngFor="let details of detail" >{{details.CountryCode}}
                  </option>
                </select>     
                <button (click)="filterCountry()">button</button>  
             </div>
`
```

``

ts code

```
` ngOnInit(){   

    this.dataService.getUserDetail().subscribe(details=>{(this.detail=details)});
 }`
```

**Result**

[This is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nEtP.png)                             -----------------------------------
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfY99.png)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use set to remove duplicate items.

first define a new property for your component:

```
  countryCodes: string[] = [];
```

then populate it with:

ngOnInit(){

```
this.dataService.getUserDetail().subscribe(details => { (this.countryCodes = this.getCountryCodes(details))});
```

}

and dd this method to the component:

```
 getCountryCodes(items: { CountryCode: string, "Prof_ID": number, Scope: string }[]) {
    const set = new Set<string>();
    items.forEach(item => (set.add(item.CountryCode)));
    return Array.from(set);
  }
```

and change your html:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of countryCodes">{{item}}
```